# How to convert this jquery code to "raw" javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me convert this jquery code into javascript (that doesn't require the jquery library)?

```
var console={
    panel:$(parent.document.body),
    log:function(m){
        this.panel.find("#something").append(m)
    }
};
```

Comment: why? what's the issue with Jquery ?

Comment: find -> document.getElementById (because of id selector), append -> parentNode.appendChild

Comment: @Ravi It's due to limitations of the project I'm working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var console = {
    panel : parent.document.body || document.body,
    log : function(m){
        this.panel.getElementById("something").appendChild( document.createTextNode(m));
    }
};
```

Comment: for some reason I'm getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLBodyElement] has no method 'getElementById'`

Comment: @AdonisK. That may be happening because the `panel` isn't found. That means that `parent.document.body` does not exist; it is only available if your code is running in an iframe. See the update and try again.

Comment: Ya, that's because it is inside an iframe. I'm trying to catch the output of the iframe's console and print it inside `#something`.